# apple push notification with iPhone

Tags: iphone, notifications, push

I would like to ask some suggestions to the experts who have faced similar problem as mine.

I am developing an iPhone application almost like a social networking application. This requires inviting friends to the application. The application is integrated with Facebook for login purpose. My question is that,

1)  We can identify the Facebook friends who are using our application. We need to send notification (push notification) to iPhones of the friends who are using our application. Our backend is deployed in AWS. So that we have SNS and SQS for notification purpose. But it supports email and SMS notifications. I came to know from the web that there is Apple push notification services. Can we use apple push notification for this purpose? Which one is preferred here? SNS or apple push notification. Please advice. If you have any reference sites please give it to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send APNS you need to have token of the device, so you can't send such notification just with the information about Facebook account. But if you are able to know that person is friend from Facebook and he uses your app, you can store some data, like token and facebook login of every user to send them APNS. But! Apple may reject it, because they hate when developers collect data that can identify a person.

APNS is nice for that situation, but risky. (Can anyone proof me wrong or right?)

Email is old-fashioned, but legal and easy to implement, i guess. Like, twitter sends push and email.

Also, you can use Facebook features (not so nice if you will integrate more social networks)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use AWS SNS and APNS for what you want to do. You will need the pushTokens for the app/device that you are wanting to send push notifications as they act as the identifiers for the specific app/device to use as an endpoint.

You need to set up an SNS topic. Then you need to subscribe the devices (with the apps of interest) to the topic. Then you can publish to the topic (either programatically or via AWS Management console) and that message will propagate to all of the topics subscribed devices (termed endpoints).

AWS has a tutorial that walks you through this process: I have not tried it yet myself.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html